# Getting XMLHttpRequest to work on Windows Phone HTML5 App

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, xmlhttprequest, windows-phone

In Microsoft Visual Studio Express I have started a new project using the "Windows Phone HTML5 App" template. If I run the emulator, everything works fine. Next I added the following JavaScript to the index.html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){

      alert(window.location.href); // -->  x-wmapp0:/Html/index.html

      var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
         alert('ON READY STATE CHANGE');
         if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
          }
       }

       //xmlhttp.open("GET","text.txt",true); // I have tried all of these
       //xmlhttp.open("GET","Html/text.txt",true);
       //xmlhttp.open("GET","/Html/text.txt",true);

       xmlhttp.open("GET","x-wmapp0:/Html/text.txt",true);
       xmlhttp.send();
   }

</script>
```

Now when I run the app in the emulator I get the first alert with the window location, but do not get any alerts from the `readyState` or `onreadystatechange`. The text.txt file is on the same level as the index.html. I have run this code in IE10 and it works just fine. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

**Update**: I have deployed this on an actual Windows 8 phone and got the same result

Cheers

Comment: Did you check for `xmlhttp.status == 200`?

Comment: Yeah, you could check for any status, the `onreadystatechange` function doesn't seem to be firing at all.

Comment: Do you have that `alert()` in your live code? IE sometimes refuses to run any code properly that uses `alert()` for some reason.

Comment: I've taken out the alerts and there is still no success

Comment: Did you make sure your path in your `open()` method is correct? You would have to have that host on your phone for that to work.

Comment: I tried both absolute and relative urls, and got the absolute path from `window.location.href`, the files are in the same location on the app, i'm not sure what you mean by hosting, the files deployed in the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what Microsoft told me from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/cd2d798c-39f0-4cb5-bb11-340dcf069310/getting-xmlhttprequest-to-work-on-windows-phone-html5-app?forum=wpdevelop)

XMLHttpRequest only works for retrieving network resources.  i.e. You cannot use it to access content from your applications local storage, i.e. XAP or IsolatedStorage.

Here is an example of script + code which I have used in the past to work around this limitation:

HTML Page with JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
  <title>test</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

      function LoadFile(SourceURL) {
          try {
              var httpfreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
              httpfreq.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  filecontent.innerText = "httpfreq.onreadystatechange fired, readyState = " + httpfreq.readyState.toString();
                  if (httpfreq.readyState = 4) {
                      filecontent.innerText = "Status = " + httpfreq.status.toString();
                      if (httpfreq.status = 200) {
                          window.external.notify("Received content" + httpfreq.responseText);
                          filecontent.innerHTML = httpfreq.responseText;
                      }
                      else {
                          window.external.notify("Error loading page: " + SourceURL);
                          filecontent.innerText = "Error loading page " + SourceURL;
                      }
                  }
              };

              httpfreq.open("GET", SourceURL);
              httpfreq.send(null);

          }
          catch (e) {
              if (e.number = 0x80070005) {
                  LoadLocalFile(SourceURL, "GetResourceCallback");
              }
              else {
                  alert(e.name + " " + e.number.toString());
              }
          }
      }

      function LoadLocalFile(SourceURL, callbackfn) {
          window.external.notify("GetResource?file=" + SourceURL + ";callback=" + callbackfn);
      }

      function GetResourceCallback(StringContent) {
          filecontent.innerText = StringContent;
      }


  </script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p> 
test page: notes.html
</p> 
    <p><input type="button" onclick="LoadFile('text.txt')" value="Load Local" /> </p>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="LoadFile('http://www.somedomain.com/text.txt')" value="Load remote" /> </p>
    <p>---------------------------</p>
    <div id="filecontent"></div>
    <p>---------------------------</p>
</body> 
</html>
```

And the required App Host code (c#)

```
private void webBrowser1_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Script Notify : {0}",e.Value);

        if (e.Value.Contains("GetResource?file="))
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    String szArgs = e.Value;

                    string szResource = null;
                    string szCallbackFn = null;
                    char[] separators = new char[2] {'?',';'};
                    string[] parms = szArgs.Split(separators);

                    for (int i = 1; i < parms.Length; i++ )
                    {
                        if (parms[i].Contains("file="))
                        {
                            szResource = parms[i].Substring(5);
                        }
                        else if (parms[i].Contains("callback="))
                        {
                            szCallbackFn = parms[i].Substring(9);
                        }
                    }

                    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(szResource) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(szCallbackFn))
                    {
                        // read local resource.
                        string szFileContent= "Resource not found!";
                        try
                        {
                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(webBrowser1.Base))
                            {
                                // if Base is not set then assume XAP file content.
                                szFileContent = ReadXAPResource(szResource);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // else assume IsolatedStorage
                                szFileContent = ReadISOFile(webBrowser1.Base, szResource);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {}

                        webBrowser1.InvokeScript(szCallbackFn, szFileContent);
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    private string ReadXAPResource(string szFile)
    {
        string szContent = "File Not Found";
        try
        {
            // in my project HTML files are in the HelpContent folder...
            StringBuilder szPath = new StringBuilder("HelpContent");
            if (!szFile.StartsWith("/"))
                szPath.Append("/");

            szPath.Append(szFile);

            StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(szPath.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));

            if (null != sri)
            {
                StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(sri.Stream);
                szContent = strm.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return szContent;
    }

    private string ReadISOFile(string szBase, string szFile)
    {
        string szContent = "File Not Found";
        try
        {
            string fullPath = szBase + szFile;
            IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            IsolatedStorageFileStream isfsInput = isf.OpenFile(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

            if (null != isfsInput)
            {
                StreamReader strm = new StreamReader(isfsInput);
                szContent = strm.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }

        return szContent;
    }
```

Comment: FYI `e.number = 0x80070005` is missing an `=` and for me it is -2147024891 (note the minus)

Comment: also an uri requested in `GetResourceStream` must not start with a `/`, took me a while to find out.

Comment: @eivers88 How would you about it to pass an byte array to a javascript? I've tried calling InvokeScript with a byte array but it only accept scripts which makes sense, but I'm trying to figure out how to use this with pdf.js as XMLHttpRequest does not appear to work with it when used in wp8.1